# mount error(13): Permission denied

Tags: windows, mount, fstab

I am trying to share a folder from Windows 10, and mount on my Raspberry Pi 3. These are the steps I followed.

1. Changed the permissions of a folder in windows, to give it full access to everyone.
2. Created a new user in that Windows system with username=BB, password=123.
3. Updated and upgraded Pi, and then installed samba, samba-common-bin, cifs-utils.
4. Connected Pi to Windows using ethernet cable, through a static IP.
5. Wrote the following line in fstab.
6. `//169.254.168.190/Documents /home/pi/testbuy cifs
   username=BB,password=123,uid=1002,iocharset=utf8,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,vers=2.0
   0     0`
7. Executed the command `sudo mount -a`

---

But I am getting permission denied error, tried all the versions, and tried to change add sec parameters. None of them worked.

Comment: 169.254.168.190 is a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. Change to `vers=3.0` to use the newest version of the protocol.
2. Manually mount with `sudo mount -t cifs -o username=BB,... //169.254... /home/pi/testbuy`
3. Use `smbclient //169.254...` to test it with an interactive client
4. `dmesg | tail -n10` to see if there are any kernel messages with hints